# Error: Bad parameter: OUR_VALIDATOR_PUBKEY (and possibly OUR_URL) must be specified unless --our-localhost is given

Tags: solana

I'm running `solana catchup` with my solana blockchain node, and I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Bad parameter: OUR_VALIDATOR_PUBKEY (and possibly OUR_URL) must be specified unless --our-localhost is given
```

I've tried adding `--our-localhost` and a few other flags to add our internal http endpoint, but nothing seems to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`--url` is taken from your config file. You can use `-u t` or `-u m` to override it to `testnet` or `mainnet`.

You don't need a local key if you use `--our-validator`. If that doesn't work, either the public APIs are being slammed or you have a networking problem.

Comment: Hmm... I tried --url too. Maybe I'm doing something else?

Comment: Show the entire command you are running and the output.